# I cannot put PyTorch model to device (.to(device))

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, autoencoder

So I was writing my first ever autoencoder, here is the code (it can be a little bit goofy, but I believe I written all of it right):

```
class Autoencoder(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
        
        self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        
        self.enc_conv0 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),

            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128)
        )
        
        self.enc_conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),

            nn.Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=(1, 1)),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(512)
        )
        
        self.enc_fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=512*64*64, out_features=4096),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(4096),
            
            nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=2048),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(2048),
            
            nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=dim_code)
        )
        
        self.dec_fc = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(in_features=dim_code, out_features=2048),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(2048),
            
            nn.Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=4096),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(4096),
            
            nn.Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=512*64*64),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm1d(512*64*64)
        )
        
        self.dec_conv0 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=256, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(256),
            
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=128, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
        )
        
        self.dec_conv1 = nn.Sequential(
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
            
            nn.ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=3, kernel_size=(3,3), padding=1)
        )

    def forward(self, x):
        e0 = self.enc_conv0(x)
        e1 = self.enc_conv1(e0)
        latent_code = self.enc_fc(self.flatten(e1))
        
        d0 = self.dec_fc(latent_code)
        d1 = self.dec_conv0(d0.view(-1, 512, 64, 64))
        reconstruction = self.dec_conv1(d1)

        return reconstruction, latent_code
```

And then I was preparing to train it with the next cell of code:

```
`device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)

criterion = nn.BCELoss()
print('crit')

autoencoder = Autoencoder().to(device)
print('deviced')`
```

Cell prints:
cuda
'crit'

And then just stalks infinitely, filling the RAM and CPU at its full (im doing everything on kaggle notebook). And I dont get why. :(

Tried to launch the same notebook in Google colab instead of Kaggle, but it just crashed with error about trying to allocate resources that are not accessable.

Also I thought the issue could had something to do with the first line after initiation of a class, so I replaced

```
def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
```

with

```
def __init__(self):
        super(Autoencoder, self).__init__()
```

like I saw in some tutorials (honestly I don't know what this lines do, it just written in every other similar cases)
But it also didnt worked

Comment: Did you try creating a single conv2d() and test its device assignement?

Comment: "it just crashed with error about trying to allocate resources that are not accessable." please provide the full error backtrace.

Comment: Did you try reducing the size of your model maybe? If I were you, I might consider trying fewer parameters, probably not a lot of VRAM if it's a Kaggle notebook.

Comment: @brock-brown, I tried to make simple model with only 1 conv and 2 fc layers for encoder and decoder and it works! So maybe the problem really was the size, thank you! But I am still not shure why that size of model was too much, because earlier I managed to write whole Unet in Kaggle notebook.

Comment: @Ivan, it says 'the session is terminated because the amount of RAM is completely exhausted.', and the log just says 'WARNING:root:kernel 0da7c92c-655b-4fb0-9992-22c2d146a325 restarted'

Answer (score 1):

So the issue was the size of the model, once I tried to make smaller one all the problems disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already found out the problem, but this answer could still be helpful to others."

First count how many parameters each layer of your model has:

- `Linear(in_features=N, out_features=M)` has `MxN` weights;
- `Flatten` and `ReLU` have no weights;
- Both `BatchNorm1d(C)` and `BatchNorm2d(C)` have `2xC` weights (2 per channel);
- Both `Conv2d` and `ConvTranspose2d(in_features=N, out_features=M, kernel_size=K, ...)` have `M` different filters, each of size `NzKxK`. Each filter has also (by default) its own bias (another weight). Therefore, for `Conv2d` layers, you end up with `MxNxKxK + M` weights.

If you compute the total number of weights of your model, you should end up with `8,599,888,384 + 2048 x dim_code + 8,604,081,155 + 2048 x dim_code = 17,203,969,539 + 4,096 x dim_code` different parameters (I hope I dind't miscalculate anything! I leave the computations in the bottom of the answer). This is even larger than most recent LLMs, such as Mistral7B (which, as the name itself suggests, has around `7B` parameters).

Now, considering that PyTorch defaults to a `float32` data type for tensors, your model needs more than `17B x 32bit = 64 GiB` of RAM. This calculation disregards the contribution from the `4,096 x dim_code` term, assuming that `dim_code` is relatively small in comparison. Therefore, make sure your machine has enough RAM (if you are using CPU as device, or enough VRAM, if you use a GPU).

### Number of parameters calculation

Encoder has `8,599,888,384 + 2048 x dim_code`:

- `enc_conv0` has:

  - `Conv2d(in_channels=3, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)` has
    `3x64x3x3+64 = 1,792` weights;
  - `BatchNorm2d(64)` has `2x64 = 128` weights;
  - `Conv2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)` has
    `128x64x3x3+128 = 73,856` weights;
  - `BatchNorm2d(128)` has `2x128 = 256` weights;
- `enc_conv1` has:

  - `Conv2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)` has
    `256x128x3x3+256 = 295,168` weights;
  - `BatchNorm2d(256)` has `2x256 = 512` weights;
  - `Conv2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=512, kernel_size=3, padding=1)` has `512x256x3x3+512 = 1,180,160` weights;
  - `BatchNorm2d(512)` has `2x512 = 1,024` weights
- `enc_fc` has:

  - `Linear(in_features=512*64*64, out_features=4096)` has `512x64x64x4096 = 8,589,934,592` weights;
  - `BatchNorm1d(4096)` has `2x4096 = 8,192` weights;
  - `Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=2048)` has `4096x2048 = 8,388,608` weights;
  - `BatchNorm1d(2048)` has `4096` weights;
  - `Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=d)` has `2048xd` weights;

Decoder has `8,604,081,155 + 2048 x dim_code` weights:

- `dec_fc` has:

  - `Linear(in_features=dim_code, out_features=2048)` has `dim_code x 2048` weights;
  - `BatchNorm1d(2048)` has `2x2048 = 4,096` weights;
  - `Linear(in_features=2048, out_features=4096)` has `2048x4096 = 8,388,608` weights;
  - `BatchNorm1d(4096)` has `2x4096 = 8,192` weights;
  - `Linear(in_features=4096, out_features=512*64*64)` has `4096x512x64x64 = 8,589,934,592` weights;
  - `BatchNorm1d(512*64*64)` has `2x512x64x64 = 4,194,304` weights;
- `dec_conv0` has:

  - `ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=512, out_channels=256, kernel_size=3, padding=1)` has `256x512x3x3 + 256 = 1,179,904` weights;
  - `BatchNorm2d(256)` has `512` weights;
  - `ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=256, out_channels=128, kernel_size=3, padding=1)` has `128x256x3x3 + 128 = 295,040` weights;
  - `BatchNorm2d(128)` has `2x128 = 256` weights;
- `dec_conv1` has :

  - `ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=128, out_channels=64, kernel_size=3, padding=1)` has `64x128x3x3 + 64 = 73,792` weights;
  - `BatchNorm2d(64)` has `2x64 = 128` weights;
  - `ConvTranspose2d(in_channels=64, out_channels=3, kernel_size=3, padding=1)` has `3x64x3x3 + 3 = 1,731` weights.

Answer (score -2):

Here's an updated version of your training code incorporating the suggestions:

```py
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

device = torch.device('cuda' if torch.cuda.is_available() else 'cpu')
print(device)

criterion = nn.MSELoss()  # Use Mean Squared Error for image reconstruction
print('crit')

autoencoder = Autoencoder().to(device)
print('deviced')
```

If the problem persists, try addressing the points mentioned above and let me know if you encounter any specific errors or if you have additional details about the issue.